# How to check an array is exist or not?

Tags: html, arrays, jsp

I am new in java, I am developing an application, where I found some difficulties. Can anyone tell me how to check that an array is set or not, means the array is exist or not.

Actually I'm getting error when I run my jsp page which contains a listing of data with a HTML form. When I submit the form and get results it works fine, but very first time to open the page it doesn't get that resultant array and give the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it works on submitting the form but not on first load it is more than likley you are trying to retreieve the post/get values when they don't yet exist.  Try checking if they are null before using them.

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking if the array is empty or not like this:

```
<c:if test="${!empty array}">
  //list the array
</c:if>
```

`empty` is an `EL` operator which return true if array is null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a variable has been initialized or not by checcking if == null or not.